# Minimizing a functional subject to boundary conditions

Tags: calculus-of-variations, boundary-value-problem, constraints, euler-lagrange-equation, variational-analysis

I want to find a smooth function $y : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ that minimizes

$$
S = \int_0^1 (y(x)y'''(x) + 3 y'(x) y''(x))^2 dx
$$
subject to the constraints / boundary conditions: (i) $y(0)=1$, (ii) $y(1)=0$, (iii) $y'(0)=0$, (iv) $y'(1)=0$.

What is the right approach for this? If I solve the unconstrained Euler-Poisson equation I get the square root of a fifth order polynomial, but this solution cannot satisfy all four constraints.

I understand how to implement constraints via Lagrange multipliers if the constraints are themselves differential equations, but is there a similar way to implement these boundary conditions?

(This is probably a duplicate of some sort, but I couldn't find the answer, mainly, I assume, because I don't know the right keyword to search for.)

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, I might be happy knowing just the minimal value for $S$, even if I don't find the explicit form of the minimizing $y(x)$.

With a mix of partial integration, Cauchy-Schwarz, and Taylor's theorem, I managed to show that $S \geq 1$ must hold, which is something already.

Comment: There is no need for Lagrange multipliers, since the boundary/initial conditions are here to determine the constants of integration only, but you must solve the Euler-Lagrange equation associated to $S$. However, where does this example come from ? Are you sure that a closed form exists ? Because the corresponding Euler-Lagrange equation will be a (nasty) sixth-order nonlinear ODE.

Comment: @Abezhiko Thanks. As mentioned, the sixth order nonlinear ODE has a simple solution, namely the square root of an arbitrary fifth order polynomial (i.e. with six free parameters). But that type of function is incompatible with the boundary conditions. There also is an obvious solution satisfying all four BCs: 2t^3-3t^2+1, which results in S=1152/7. Starting with a higher polynomial ansatz one can also easily find functions y(x) that satisfy the BCs and result in lower S. What I need to know is, how small can S get? (I don't actually need the corresponding y(x), just the minimal S.)

Comment: PS: Putting the Euler-Poisson equation together with the boundary conditions into Mathematica and trying to DSolve says that there are no solutions.

Comment: Euler-Poisson??

Comment: @Qmechanic I mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations#Euler%E2%80%93Poisson_equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to WolframAlpha, the explicit expression of the Euler-Poisson equation associated with $S$ is
$$
-20y(y''')^2-30yy''y^{(4)}-12yy'y^{(5)}-2y^2y^{(6)}=0, \tag{1}
$$
which can be simplified to $y(y^2)^{(6)}=0$. Therefore, the solutions to $(1)$ are
$y(x)=0$ or $y(x)=\pm\sqrt{p(x)}$, where $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4+a_5x^5$ is an arbitrary$^{(*)}$ fifth-degree polynomial.
The boundary conditions $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=0$ further imply that $y(x)=+\sqrt{p(x)}$, with $a_0=1$ and $a_1=0$. In addition, $y(1)=0$ implies
$$
1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5=0. \tag{2}
$$
To enforce the fourth boundary condition, $y'(1)=0$, is less straightforward: since the denominator of $y'(x)=\frac{p'(x)}{2\sqrt{p(x)}}$ vanishes at $x=1$, we require that not only $p'(1)=0$, i.e.
$$
2a_2+3a_3+4a_4+5a_5=0, \tag{3}
$$
but also that $p''(1)=0$:
$$
2a_2+6a_3+12a_4+20a_5=0. \tag{4}
$$
In other words, $x=1$ must be a triple root of $p(x)$.

The system of equations $(2)$-$(4)$ is underdetermined; it has the one-parameter family of solutions
$$
(a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)=(-t-6,3t+8,-3t-3,t). \tag{5}
$$
To determine $t$, let's plug
$$
y_t(x):=\sqrt{1-(t+6)x^2+(3t+8)x^3-(3t+3)x^4+tx^5} \tag{6}
$$
into $S[y]$ and minimize the result with respect to $t$.
Letting [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int+%28y%28x%29y%27%27%27%28x%29%2B3y%27%28x%29y%27%27%28x%29%29%5E2+dx+from+x%3D0..1+where+y%28x%29%3Dsqrt%281-%28t%2B6%29x%5E2%2B%283t%2B8%29x%5E3-%283t%2B3%29x%5E4%2Btx%5E5%29) do the hard work, we obtain the surprisingly simple result
$$
S[y_t(x)]=9t^2+48t+144. \tag{7}
$$
It's straightforward to show that the minimum of $S[y_t(x)]$ occurs at $t=-\frac{8}{3}$, where it attains the value $S_{\min}=80$. One can also check [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+sqrt%281-10%2F3x%5E2%2B5x%5E4-8%2F3x%5E5%29+from+x%3D0..1) that the function that minimizes $S$,
$$
y_{-8/3}(x)=\sqrt{1-\frac{10}{3}x^2+5x^4-\frac{8}{3}x^5}
=\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}(1-x)^3(8x^2+9x+3)}\,, \tag{8}
$$
is real in the interval $[0,1]$ and satisfies all the boundary conditions.

---

$^{(*)}$ To be precise, not completely arbitrary: $p(x)$ must be nonnegative in the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you for the effort! You are my hero. However, I am a bit confused about your equation (6), which still leaves $y_t'(x)$ ill-defined at $x=1$. In order to avoid this, I would need to demand also $p'''(1) = 0$, i.e. $a_5 = 4$, which completely determines $y(x) = (1-x)^2 \sqrt{1+4x}$ which results in $S_\text{min} = 480$. Is this right, or am I missing something?

Comment: You're probably missing something. Differentiating $(6)$ with respect to $x$ one finds $$y_t'(x)=\frac{x(1-x)^2(5tx-2t-12)}{2\sqrt{(1-x)^3(1+3x-tx^2)}}=\frac{1}{2}x(5tx-2t-12)\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+3x-tx^2}}\,.$$Therefore, $y_t'(1)=0$.

Comment: Thank you, you are right of course. I am just too stupid to use Mathematica correctly. Thanks again for the great answer!

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: It is potentially problematic to assume a 6th-order [Euler-Poisson (EP) equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations#Euler%E2%80%93Poisson_equation) in a higher-order variational problem without adequate boundary conditions (BCs).

1. OP's functional can be rewritten as
   $$S[z]~:=~\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \!dx~ (z^{\prime\prime\prime}(x))^2, \tag{1}$$
   where we have introduced a new variable $$z~=~y^2\tag{2}$$ which must satisfy an inequality
   $$ z(x)~\geq~0,\tag{3}$$
   which one should check in the end.
2. OP's BCs for $y$
   $$ y(0)~=~1, \quad y^{\prime}(0)~=~0, \quad  y(1)~=~0, \quad y^{\prime}(1)~=~0, \tag{4}$$
   clearly imply the corresponding BCs for $z$
   $$ z(0)~=~1, \quad z^{\prime}(0)~=~0, \quad  z(1)~=~0, \quad z^{\prime}(1)~=~0. \tag{5}$$
   Conversely, to ensure the last BC in eq. (4) [for a sufficiently nice function $y$] we need to impose a 5th BC
   $$ z^{\prime\prime}(1)~=~0, \tag{6}$$
   as explained in [Gonçalo's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4788286/11127).
3. If we vary infinitesimally OP's functional, we calculate
   $$ \begin{align}2\delta S
   ~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~~&\int_0^1 \!dx~ z^{\prime\prime\prime}(x)~\delta z^{\prime\prime\prime}(x)\cr
   ~=~~&\int_0^1 \!dx\frac{d}{dx}\left(z^{\prime\prime\prime}(x)~\delta z^{\prime\prime}(x)\right)-\int_0^1 \!dx~ z^{(4)}(x)~\delta z^{\prime\prime}
   \cr
   ~\stackrel{(5)+(6)}{=}&-z^{\prime\prime\prime}(0)~\delta z^{\prime\prime}(0)-\int_0^1 \!dx~ z^{(6)}(x)~\delta z. 
   \end{align}\tag{7} $$
4. Now for the 6th-order EP equation
   $$ z^{(6)}(x)~=~0. \tag{8}$$
   to be a stationary solution, we need a 6th BC
   $$z^{\prime\prime\prime}(0)~=~0.\tag{9} $$
5. One may check that the minimizing 5th-order polynomial found in [Gonçalo's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4788286/11127) happens to satisfy the 6th BC (9) as well, so it is indeed a stationary solution!

   This is not a coincidence: When we minimized the functional (1) for 5th-order polynomials satisfying EP eq. (8) and BCs (5) and (6), then eq. (7) conversely implies the 6th BC (9).